# Excel VBA application.inputbox workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the name of a workbook and worksheet from the `Application.InputBox` command in excel so that I can switch between the Active Workbook, and the workbook I have selected values from using the application.

I have code that works well selecting the values as a range, so I do not want to change that.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub test()
Dim rSelectDie As Range
Dim myWorkbook As String
Dim myWorksheet As String

Set rSelectDie = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the Die Values", Type:=8)

myWorkbook = ???
myWorksheet = rSelectDie.Worksheet.Name
MsgBox "Your Worksheet is: " & myWorksheet & vbNewLine & "Your WorkBook is" & myWorkbook


Windows(myWorkbook).Activate
Sheets(myWorksheet).Activate
End Sub
```

I am not sure what to put for the "???"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps

```
myWorkbook = rSelectDie.Worksheet.Parent.Name
```

or

```
myWorkbook = rSelectDie.Parent.Parent.Name
```

Comment: This is it. That worked great! I would not have though of Parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook.Name` is that what you want ?